# How to make animation that don't failed because Angular Router add element on DOM

Tags: css, angular, animation

I have 2 components. 
HomeComponent : This is the component that display the landing page. This component translates to the top of the screen to get out during route transition.
CustomComponent : This component enter the screen from the left and take the place of the HomeComponent.

My problem is that the CustomComponent is not into the DOM before transition. When transition start, Angular router add this element into the DOM and make the HomeComponent to be pushed to the bottom. Then, the translate animation starts and home component translates off the screen by the top.

I want to avoid this bottom push and directly make the home component translate to the top of the screen.

This is my DOM structure.

```
<body>
    <header></header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

All component use relative position as the site need to be responsive.

I've try to set absolute wrapper around each component. This makes HomeComponent and CustomComponent are independant and animation  executes fine. But with this, i can't make a footer that stay behind content and at the bottom of the screen if the content does not fullfill the screen.

Any solution?

Comment: You can have absolute position for the transition, and then set the position at the end to be relative.  This way, you can have the custom element be offset at the start, and then animate its position until it overlays the HomeComponent, at which point you would then set the position back to relative.  Have you tried something like this?

Comment: No. I will try this solution

Comment: This does not work

Comment: Have exactly the same problem and couldn't find the solution.

Comment: Did you find any solution?